# Windows nslookup xyz works, but ping xyz gives "host not found"

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-sbs-2011

A client is having some intermittent DNS issues; sometimes ping to a particular host works, sometimes it doesn't. `nslookup` works all the time, `ping` works sometimes and not others.

The computers are on a domain, the domain controller (on IP `192.168.3.5`) runs a DNS service that I believe is correctly configured to pass queries on to the router if it cannot resolve. The router (on `192.168.3.1`) is a ddwrt affair, downstream of the ISP's router. Client computers are configured to first approach the domain controller, then the ddwrt router. The domain controller DNS forwarding is configured to try the ISP router, then google public DNS. The ddwrt router is configured to use the ISP router as its primary, and google public DNS as secondary. The ISP router has its own DNS config that is left alone.

The hostnames that give trouble are used in development of IIS websites, a DNS wildcard states that `*.machine.dev.visionslive.com` is a CNAME of `machine.visionslive.com`, and that in itself is set to resolve to the internal IP of the machine on the network. This allows developers to use IIS host headers of whatever subdomain of `machinex.visionslive.com` they want when developing websites

Here's a console log of nslookup (using both on-lan DNS servers) vs ping:

[image]

The confusing thing is that sometimes ping works just fine, other times not. It also affects all configured hostnames (machinex.dev.visionslive.com) simultaneously.

Clearing the cache in the DNS snap-in on the SBS server, anecdotally, seems to make things work again. I say anecdotally because there hasn't been a dedicated 30 seconds where a conversation like "oh, it's not working. I'll clear the cache. Oh look, it's working now" hasn't occurred - it has just been just noticed that "at some point it wasn't working, some time later the cache was cleared, and some time later again, things worked". All hosts on the network suffer this problem, not just those running HyperV (as per the pictured example)

Here's a shot of the SBS2011 DNS setup, together with a "how the clear-cache that may get it working again, is performed", if it helps:

[image]

Comment: OK, do yourself a favor; configure the DNS client settings on all domain joined machines, including the Domain Controller, to use only the Domain Controller for DNS. In the DNS **server** settings on the DC you can configure it to use your router as a forwarder, or use Google's public DNS servers as forwarders, or both, or any other forwarders you'd like to use. You can configure your router to use any forwarders you like. To repeat: **ALL DOMAIN CLIENTS, INCLUDING THE DOMAIN CONTROLLER, SHOULD ONLY USE THE DOMAIN CONTROLLER IN THEIR DNS CLIENT SETTINGS**. Reboot the DC, then the clients.

Comment: Done (on my client; i'll see if it carries on working when the other client machine quits), thanks!